# Find separating curve between two types of points

Tags: python

In the following plot, it looks like there is a clear separating curve between the 'x' and 'o'. It seems to be a smooth non-linear curve.

How can I find this curve, and possibly attempt to fit it with some formula?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you provide the way you have generated it?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It is a question about statistics/machine learning. [statistics.se] would be a better fit.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am more interested in the practical approach rather than the theory behind it.

Comment: @Cukic0d Unfortunately, these points were not generated in a simple way

Comment: @Joshhh [statistics.se] isn't just a place for theoretical discussion. It *does* focus on practical solutions to practical questions. There really isn't a drop of programming in your question, so it doesn't seem to be on-topic here.